# Show-Hide depending on select option

Tags: jquery

This seems like something straightforward, but this isn't working. The idea is to show something in a span tag, depending on a select statement..it works to hide the span but won't show the span.  Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the select statement where the values are 1 or 0

```
<SELECT NAME="myname" id="showdesc">
    <OPTION VALUE="1">Yes</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0" >No</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<span id="secret">Some content</span>
```

Here is the jquery that looks for the values in the select statement

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#showdesc', function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() == '1'){
        jQuery('span').show('#secret');
    }else{
        jQuery('span').remove('#secret')};
});
```

Comment: `remove` deletes the element from the DOM. The oposite of `show` is `hide`. When in doubt, read the documentation first: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `show` method improperly.

***First***, select the proper element/s.

***Then***, apply the `show`/`hide` `jQuery` method:

---

Change:

```
if(jQuery(this).val() == '1')
{
    jQuery('span').show('#secret');
}
else
{
    jQuery('span').remove('#secret')
};
```

To:

```
if(jQuery(this).val() == '1')
{
    $('#secret').show();
}
else
{
    $('#secret').hide();
};
```

---

[jQuery.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: This is the right answer, but people like explanations. I'm not a fan of using code blind code, you know what I mean? You should talk about each function and why using the ones you used is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling .remove, which will remove the element from the DOM, which when you subsequently want to show, the item will not be available.

Instead, try:

```
jQuery('#secret').show();
jQuery('#secret').hide();
```